# Incorrect output when computing the distance in kilometres of the Great Circle using Haversine formula in Java

Tags: java, great-circle

I'm trying to compute the distance in kilometres of the Great Circle using Haversine formula in Java as shown below

```
/* Program to demonstrate the Floating-point numbers and the Math library.
 * The great-circle distance is the length of the shortest path between two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) on the surface of a sphere, where the path is constrained to be along the surface.*/
public class GreatCircle 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double r = 6371.0; // Equatorial radius of the Earth
        double x1 = Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(args[0]));
        double y1 = Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(args[1]));
        double x2 = Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(args[2]));
        double y2 = Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(args[3]));

        // Compute using Haversine formula
        double distance = 2 * r * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.sin((x2 - x1) / 2),2 + Math.cos(x2) * Math.pow(Math.sin((y2 - y1) / 2),2)));

        // Output the distance
        System.out.println(distance + " kilometers ");
    }
}
```

I'm running with input `java GreatCircle 60.0 15.0 120.0 105.0`. The expected output is `4604.53989281927 kilometers`, But I get `13406.238676180266 kilometers`. Could someone please point out where am I going wrong?

Comment: This might be more appropriate on the [math stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `Math.pow(Math.sin(y2 - y1 / 2)` y1 getscasted to an int in the last power i don’t think you want that you should probably write y1 / 2.0 instead of y1 / 2.

Comment: The same for x1 in the first power.

Comment: @user16320675 I thought there was an integer division since I had a similar problem some time ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula was implemented incorrectly. It worked after making the following corrections.
In the formula, we are taking the arc sin of the entire expression.

```
        // Compute using Haversine formula
        double distance = 2 * r * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.sin((x2 - x1) / 2),2 + Math.cos(x2) * Math.pow(Math.sin((y2 - y1) / 2),2)));

        // Output the distance
        System.out.println(distance + " kilometers ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Perhaps I need to rework on the implementation of the formula. I might get back to this sometime in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**You have forgotten to calculate `Math.cos(x1) * Math.cos(x2)`, that's why you get a different result.**

````
// Compute using Haversine formula<br>
double distance = 2 * r * Math.asin(Math.sqrt((Math.pow(Math.sin((x2 - x1) / 2),2) + Math.cos(x1) * Math.cos(x2) * Math.pow(Math.sin((y2 - y1) / 2),2))));```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
double distance = 2 * r * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.sin((x2 - x1) / 2),2)
            + Math.cos(x2) * Math.cos(x1) * Math.pow(Math.sin((y2 - y1) / 2),2)));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).