# 'NaN' output when computing the distance in kilometers of the Great Circle using Haversine formula in Java

Tags: java, haversine

*I tried using the top formula of distance from the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70447203/incorrect-output-when-computing-the-distance-in-kilometres-of-the-great-circle-u?answertab=trending#tab-top) but it display 'NaN'; can someone tell me where I got it wrong. Also, sometimes it doesn't go 'NaN' but the answer is still inaccurate. I'm a beginner.*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Great_Circle{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        double r = 6371.0;
        double x1 = scanner.nextDouble();
        double y1 = scanner.nextDouble();
        double x2 = scanner.nextDouble();
        double y2 = scanner.nextDouble();

        double distance = 2 * r * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.sin((x2 - x1) / 2),2 + 
        Math.cos(x2) * Math.pow(Math.sin((y2 - y1) / 2),2))));

        System.out.println(distance + " kilometers ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Math.sin and Math.cos expect values in radians.  Are your inputs in radians?

Answer (score 0):

`ASin` is valid on the range `[1; 1]`. Function spec is saying:

> **If the argument is NaN or its absolute value is greater than 1, then the result is NaN.**
> If the argument is zero, then the result is a zero with the same sign as the argument.

However this `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.sin((x2 - x1) / 2),2 +  Math.cos(x2) * Math.pow(Math.sin((y2 - y1) / 2),2)))` seems returning value out of the range.

Hence you get `NaN`.